# Functions and Graphs - How to find equation of a straight line with only 1 given point

Tags: functions, conic-sections

can anyone help me with this question especially the first one...I don't know how to find the equation of the line as i'm only given one point.

[image]

Comment: Can you find $Q$? (Hint: By symmetry of a parabola...)

Comment: Where the parabola intersects the $x$-axis closest to the origin, does that say $I$ or $1$? And we haven't been given that $Q$ is on the $x$-axis, but it looks like that's the case.

Comment: Hi there, so i have two points on my straight line V(-3,4) and Q which intersects the x-axis. Then i've been given the the vertex R(3,2). The straight line intersects at P and Q. The point S and T lie on the parabola and straight line, between P and Q. The line ST is parallel to the y-axis. Where the parabola intersects the x axis closes to the origin says 1.

Comment: I have attempted the first question but i am lost, i have found the equation of the parabola, using the point where the parabola passes through the x-axis closest to the origin (1,0) and the vertex R(3,2) however i am not sure if it is correct. i got g(x)=1/2x^2+3/2?

Comment: In the future please help us help you by including important parts of your question—in this case, pretty much the entire question—as text instead of pasting a picture of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to find the point Q. Because the parabola is symmetric about the axis of symmetry, $x = 3$, if $(1,0)$ is on the parabola, then $(5,0)$ is Q. Now we have two points on the line, $(-3,4)$, and $(5,0)$. I'm sure you can find the slope and use the point-slope formula to figure out the equation line.

Now to find the equation of the parabola, just use the vertex form: $y = a(x-h)^2 + k$. The vertex, $(h,k)$ is $(3,2)$. Plug in $3$ for $h$, and $2$ for $k$. Now, plug in $1$ (or  $5$) for $x$, and $0$ for $y$. From this, you should be able to figure out a.